# sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python's Regular Expression module and I am trying to find any occurrence of the following:

```
PWSCF        :    18.81s CPU        38.94s WALL
```

I tried using the following Regular Expression

```
pat=re.compile("PWSCF\s+:\s+([\d\.\]+)\s\s+\CPU")
```

I ended up with the following error message:

```
File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, 
in _compile raise error, v # invalid expression 
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping the closing bracket you need remove backslash also you don't need to escape the regex tokens within character-class like `.` in your question :

```
>>> pat=re.compile("PWSCF\s+:\s+([\d.]+)\s\s+\CPU")
```

Comment: Backslash, not forward slash.

Comment: @abarnert mmm yep :D tnx!